# css: how to vertically align table within div

Tags: css

i want to vertically align the second table to the top of the div.  i have tried `style="vertical-align:top;"` but it does not seem to work.  code:

```
<div class="q">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><table>
```

Comment: `vertical-top;` isn't valid CSS...

Comment: typing mistake on my part ~ it has been edited @BoltClock♦

Comment: Code is not complete and the CSS property is `vertical-align:top;`

Comment: I see nested tables.... are you sure that it's not the inner table which is misaligned? What does IE tools say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `vertical-align` property on the `td`

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6JvLp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, fixed it by applying style="vertical-align: top;" to the td tag